# How to make a label change its text every some time in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a label that I want to update every 5 seconds. It should change from 1921 to 1922 onward till 1992. I have tried using a timer but it gave me an error about being accessed on the wrong thread. The code I used was:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x = 1921;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        private void UpdateLabel(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = x.ToString();
            x += 1;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTimer.Elapsed += UpdateLabel;
            myTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Comment: Use the Timer that is in the TOOLBOX.  Handle its Elapsed() event...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void UpdateLabel(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Invoke makes the UI thread call the delegate.
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {label1.Text = x.ToString(); });
    x += 1;
}
```

Comment: It would be `BeginInvoke()`, not `Invoke()` (you risk a deadlock). You cannot do this: `x += 1;` here (you can `Interlocked.Increment()` it, though)

Comment: How would I use Interlocked.Increment()?

Comment: You shouldn't. See the comment of Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp. Using that Timer, you don't need to **BeginInvoke()** or `Lock` or `Interlock` anything. The Tick event is raised in the UI Thread. If you actually need a form of threading, there are other means.

Comment: I was trying that, but then I couldn't figure out how to cause something to happen every 5 loops without something going wrong.

Comment: If other methods are accessing the "label.Text" or the "i" variable you should consider using BeginInvoke() and Interlocked.Increment(). The way you posted there is no racing condition (different threads acessing the resource at the same time).
Also System.Windows.Forms.Timer should work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   private readonly object y = new object();
    int x = 1921;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    private void UpdateLabel(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { lock (y) { label1.Text = x.ToString(); x++; } }));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Elapsed += UpdateLabel;
        myTimer.Start();
    }
```